# React: Implementing a hook to fetch data and return loading state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement a hook (`useFetch(route, dependencies=[])`) which will be used to `fetch` data and return a scalar value, `loading`, which is used to determine if the user is currently fetching new data.

This works as expected *on the initial* render (as the default state for `loading` is true).

The problem occurs on every subsequent render. Due to the `loading` state being currently set to `false` (after the initial render), the `loading` state will remain false for an extra render cycle before it is updated to true at the top of the `useEffect()`.

How can I prevent that extra `loading=false` render cycle, so the component I use this `useFetch()` in is immediately aware that data is currently being fetched and that I can display the `'...loading'` text in the `render()` (without having to render twice to get to this point).

**useFetch**

```
function useFetch(route, successHandler, dependencies = []) {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        fetch(route,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({}),
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                () => {
                  // Set state data from component here 
                  successHandler();
                }, 
                () => {/*...*/})
            .finally(() => {
                setLoading(false);
            });
    }, dependencies);
    return loading;
}
```

**Component**

```
function Component(){
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState({});
  const loading = useFetch('endpoint', 
    () => setOptions({foo: 'bar'}), 
    [toggle]);

  return <div>
    <button onClick={()=>{setToggle(!toggle)}}>Trigger useFetch()</button>
    {loading ? '...loading': options.foo}
  </div>;
}
```

Any help or design suggestions would be appreciated,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two mistakes:

```
const loading = useFetch('endpoint', 
    () => setOptions({foo: 'bar'}), 
    [toggle]);
```

1. The dependency array should be the variables that are used in the `useEffect`, in your case it can be `[route]`
2. `[toggle]` as a dependency parameter will send `[false]` or `[true]`, depending on your state variable. Which won't be under control of the useEffect of the hook you created.

Check out this example, it might help you understand better:

[image: Edit friendly-ives-xt5k0]

Comment: I wouldn't want toggle to be under the control of the `useEffect`, i intend for it to be used to trigger that `useEffect` instead. Does that go against the hooks rules?

Comment: Yep. It does. You need to use the variables that are used in the useEffect hook or an empty array.

Comment: Check the example I added.

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle, checking it out now